# Inconsistent TypeScript Type Inference in Conditional Statement?

Tags: typescript

My goal is to avoid repeating many times in switch cases of such checks of the existence of the `id` or `value`

**Error Message:**

```py
The argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

[**Code DEMO**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&pretty=true&ts=5.5.0-dev.20240312#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM72MgrgWzgWWFVQEMBzYOAbwCg565VgYBJGYPAXjgHInX2OHgBoaAXxo0AZlmQIYASxRwpECAAocRUhQBcBbeWDC4AExIwS+gAolYCkgBsAPACVgSKKefooC5GQmvv5kAHyhAJTUdAxIaPAKqABqTgqmcNzmlgB0aXAAhNzYjo5wAGRlZhYk2QBuTliUhXDFjgDckgyMAO4KMAgAFnCahhRRtF1dCCRMBsRG2fxsHPoTk+sKUsOJKY5p4zHrR4zMyzjqWTVpJpd1DcARHcddEsevDBISNHHoJwIcGW2pn0wQCJnqjkaIJgfgCcAAPnAIAAjABWHhgUU4oWiXSgzCwUGQcDyAGo4BDGh0JEA)

**Code snippet:**

```
export const enum Message {
    setItem = 'setItem',
}

function foo(message: Message, data: Partial<Record<string, string>>) {
    const isValid = data.id != null && data.value != null;

    switch (message) {
        case Message.setItem: {
            if (isValid) {
                setItem(data.id, data.value);
            }
        }
    }
}

const setItem = (id: string, value: string | object) => {
    return id + value;
}
```

I'm getting a type error within `setItem(data.id, data.value);`

**Additional Information:**

1. storage.setItem() expects the first argument to be a string.
2. The error seems to suggest that TypeScript is not able to infer that `event.data.data.id` is always a string, even though `isValid` should ensure this.
3. In practice I have many of these switch cases in some of them I need to check `id` in others I don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make type promotion functions in typescript: [more info](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates)

```
function isValid(element: Partial<Record<string, string>>): 
element is Partial<Record<string, string>> & {id: string, value: string}
{
    return element.id != null && element.value != null;
}
```

and you can use this in an if statement to promote your type.

```
if(isValid(data)){
    const id: string = t.id; //typescript will not complain
}
```

Comment: thank you for an excellent suggestion. Probably this is the only way to deal with this.

Comment: you should be checking for undefined instead of null also

Comment: Here is a catch :) `!= null` - it checks for undefined also - not a triple equal

Comment: oh lmao. u right

Answer (score 0):

Use [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) which tells the TS that you assert that a value is not going to be null or undefined.

```
setItem(data.id, data.value!);
```

Comment: The answer is valid, but as a developer, I'm avoiding non-null in a similar manner as `CSS !important`